# Maven modules to extend functionality of existing module

Tags: java, maven

**I currently have the following project structure:**

```
parentModule
├── moduleA
│   └── pom.xml        <--- moduleA POM
└── pom.xml            <--- parentModule POM
```

**What I am trying to achieve:**

The end result is that I want to have two different jar files which are both versions of `moduleA` but with slight differences between them. For example, one version of `moduleA` should disable a feature of it whilst also effectively overriding another feature.

I don't want the user to have to deal with configuration files or settings, just the ability to download a pre-built jar file for each of the variations.

A specific example of this is that I want one version of `moduleA` to resolve tor onion addresses to a Connection object, but I want a different version of `moduleA` to resolve just normal IP addresses to a Connection object. For this specific problem I envision creating a module that depends on `moduleA` specialised for tor usage - by adding tor libraries as dependencies and somehow overriding the current address resolution method in `moduleA` to only work with tor onion addresses.

**My current approach:**

I've been thinking that reflection might be useful in this situation and have envisioned the following project structure:

```
parentModule
├── moduleA
│   ├── src/package/Resolver.java            <--- Resolver interface
│   ├── moduleA-normal
│   │   └── src/package/ResolverImpl.java    <--- ResolverImpl implementing Resolver
│   │   └── pom.xml    <--- moduleA-normal POM
│   ├── moduleA-tor
│   │   └── src/package/ResolverImpl.java    <--- ResolverImpl implementing Resolver
│   │   └── pom.xml    <--- moduleA-tor POM
│   └── pom.xml        <--- moduleA POM
└── pom.xml            <--- parentModule POM
```

Using this approach, I suspect I can use reflection to access whichever `ResolverImpl` was compiled into the final jar.
Although, I still don't see an easy way to disable a core component of `moduleA` such as the ability to stream video. Maybe that component should stop being as much of a 'core component' as I make it, because currently I just assume it will be there. Should I do something similar to the proposed solution of address resolution above (uses of interfaces and reflection)?

Is there a better way to do what I am trying to achieve and how can I implement this properly?

Comment: There are two questions in one, aren't there? 1) How to build two slightly different JARs. 2) How to implement the differences. The trivial answer to the first is already in the second: Create two different projects. There could be also a more sophisticated one with just one project and using [Maven profiles](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html). That depends on details.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want an **external** settings file for the JARs, it might be worth while to write the code once (in a `common` module) and then create separate modules which only differ in a configuration file in the resources.

Comment: For the case I have presented, would it be more suitable to put the differing submodules inside `moduleA` and keep `moduleA` as the 'common' module?

Comment: Personally I never have a module both build an artifact and have child modules. I think it makes configuration and more difficult to understand. I would have common as a sibling of the other two modules.

Comment: @tgdavies what is `moduleA` doesn't build an artifact? I think it would probably work better to have only `moduleA-normal` and `moduleA-tor` build the artifacts

Comment: I mean that I would put `Resolver.java` in a sibling module of `moduleA-normal` and `moduleA-tor`, and make it a dependency of those two.

Comment: @tgdavies Re "_I never have a module both build an artifact and have child module_" – That''s not even possible under "normal" circumstances, i.e. with clean Maven standard POMs. [Aggregator projects](https://svn.apache.org/repos/infra/websites/production/maven/content/pom.html#Aggregation) have to have `<packaging>pom`, not `jar`, `war` or the like.

Comment: @GeroldBroser That would explain why I haven't done it :-)

Comment: @tgdavies I know (you, from here at SO). This comment was intended to be more for other current and future readers here, not exclusively for you. :-)